# How Caffe implicitly do reshape on a blob before doing fully connecting calculation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, inner-product

How does Caffe implicitly do reshape on a blob before doing fully connecting calculation?

Answer (score 2):

[`"InnerProduct"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/innerproduct.html) layer (aka "fully connected") has a `axis:` parameter that defines how caffe "flattens" the blob for the inner product.
You can see in [`inner_product_layer.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp#L18-L21):

> ```
> // Dimensions starting from "axis" are "flattened" into a single
> // length K_ vector. For example, if bottom[0]'s shape is (N, C, H, W),
> // and axis == 1, N inner products with dimension CHW are performed.
> ```

Since caffe stores Blobs contiguously in memory, no explicit reshape is needed for "flattening" the trailing dimensions of a blob.

Comment: Thank so much! So, in the detail...If let this param in default, The array of each item of a batch is flattened as: #1 channel, #2channel, ...    And in one channel it is: #1 row, #2row, ...   And in one row it is: #1 float number, #2 float number...       Isn‘t it?